# Target class does not exist. problem in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When create a new project with laravel 8 and I get this error.

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> [SayhelloController] does not exist. http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/john

```php
<?php
    
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
     
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});  
    
Route::get('/users/{name?}' , [SayhelloController::class,'index']);
```

In laravel documents Routes controller class must define like this

```
 // Using PHP callable syntax...
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);

// Using string syntax...
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
```

Target class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SayhelloController extends Controller
{
    public function index($name = null)
    {
        return 'Hello '.$name;
    }
}
```

So I did exactly.

Comment: Can you share more details, like the definition of that target class?

Comment: target class is added

Comment: You answered your own question within two minutes, why ask if you already know answer?

Comment: You forgot to add `Namespace` for controller class.

Comment: @Orhan, thats good thinking but this is not how SO works, you should first look if the problem/solution you are addressing is already solved or not, also if you wish to answer then you should add some more details too like kamlesh-paul has done, cheers :)

Comment: After having added that target class: this does look pretty unrelated to Laravel itself. Why haven't you imported that controller class in the first place?

Comment: `composer  dump-autoload`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## Laravel 8 Update the way to write routes

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade

#### in laravel 8 you need to use like

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\SayhelloController;
Route::get('/users/{name?}' , [SayhelloController::class,'index']);
```

or

```php
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
```

### If you want to use old way

then in `RouteServiceProvider.php`

add this line

```php
 /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers'; // need to add in Laravel 8
    

public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace) // need to add in Laravel 8
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace) // need to add in Laravel 8
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```

Then you can use like

```php
Route::get('/users/{name?}' , [SayhelloController::class,'index']);
Route::resource('/users' , SayhelloController::class);
```

or

```php
Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
```

Comment: Hello, i cannot open a new threat, I find this and is exactly that I need, but I use a resource controller, how can I do?

Comment: @MauEspaña i added  `resource` example as well

Comment: Today, I am facing the same problem months later when compared to this thread. In my case, the **RouteServiceProvider.php** reference was not necessary/not my case, because it was already there!

So, I´ve changed my class `StudentController` from `App\Http\Controller` dir to/subdir: `App\Http\Controller\Student\StudentController`. And ran again artisan `route:list`. The same issue happened again, but the **path** for reference called my attention: `App\Http\Controller\App\Http\Controller\Student\StudentController`. So, it means some kind of cached route. I put back the Class and worked!

Comment: For the uninitiated, you may want to mention at the top (of the answer) that one needs to include the Controller on the top of the routing file

Comment: the best way, i think with old way open `RouteServiceProvider.php` and add 
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
above public function boot() { 
for no many need change