# How to get the right routes on Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have a question about Laravel, I install Laravel 8 but the routes doen't work anymore. Can anyone help me about this problem? I tried to do the routes different but that doesn't work.

Comment: If you have worked with previous versions, the route syntax has been changed. Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing).

Comment: you can check my answer about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882034/target-class-does-not-exist-problem-in-laravel-8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

Answer (score 0):

add `$namespace` to `App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

> protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

also add `namespace` to boot function

```
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace) 
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace) 
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Answer (score -1):

in laravel 8 you can't use controller in web.php without adding namespace here is the example from my web.php
web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\YourController;

Route::get('/url', [YourController::class, 'method']);
or
Route::get('/url','App\Http\Controllers\YourController@method');
```

Answer (score -1):

Pls have a look at official documentation, this can be helpful routing is now updated

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing