# Laravel, the class exists but I get Target class [PagesController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I don't know what I am missing here.
I have this in web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
        Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    
    Route::get('/Pages', 'PagesController@index');
```

My PagesController.php is

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PagesController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

PagesController exists inside Http/Controllers file, but I get an error that says "Target class [PagesController] does not exist" when I go to /Pages. I definitely not have a typo in the class name and I have searched for solutions but nothing worked. Can anyone give me advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882034/target-class-does-not-exist-problem-in-laravel-8#answer-63882104 take a look this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What laravel version you are working on? **Laravel 6,7 or 8**.

if you are working on **Larvel 8** you can't write route like we used to before, the next syntax is this.

**Web.php:**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;

Route::get('/Pages', [PagesController::class, 'index']);
```

**or:**

```
Route::get('/Pages', '\App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index');
```

[Docs for routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing)