# Laravel 8 (version 8.35.1): Target class does not exist

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-routing

I'm using laravel 8.35.1 version. I have a api-resource controller **"ProductController"**. At my route file **api.php**. I define the route this:

**api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::apiResource('/products', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function () {
    Route::apiResource('/{product}/review', 'App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController');
});
```

**NOTE:**
It's work fine but, when i remove the complete path of controller like just write `Route::apiResource('/products', 'ProductController');` it show error

> Target class [ProductController] does not exist.

Before first clearing the **cache**. I want to get rid of the complete path. and second want to place the controllers in **Api** folder, so how to define route for that also.
I have also tried `ProductController::class` but not work fine

**Updated**
when I use the route according the laravel 8 doc. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers it is working fine. but when move the controller file to Api folder then declare the route name space like `use App\Http\Controllers\Api\ProductController;` show error again

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::apiResource('/products', ProductController::class);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function () {
    Route::apiResource('/{products}/reviews', ReviewController::class);
});
```

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882034/target-class-does-not-exist-problem-in-laravel-8/63882104#63882104

Comment: thanks alot, but @KamleshPaul please check the updated part. then how to resolve it.

Comment: Have you also updated `namespace ...;` in the controller file after moving to the `Api` sub folder to reflect that?

Comment: yes i did it @msbit. "namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;"

Comment: If the namespace in `ProductController.php` matches the corresponding `use ...` in `routes/api.php`, then it should be found. Is it exactly the same error?

Comment: @msbit yes exactly the same error

Comment: I'm not sure what it is then, it may be helpful to update the question with your current `routes/api.php` and `app/Http/Controllers/Api/ProductController.php` files.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use class on declare controller in routing.
You may change 'ProductController' instead ProductController::class

Answer (score 0):

When i try this then it work fine for me.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::apiResource('/products', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function () {
    Route::apiResource('/{product}/reviews', [ReviewController::class, 'ReviewController']);
});
```