# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException .Target class [MarketsouhaibController] does not exist. laravel 8

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

The following errors occurs in my laravel 8 application:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException .Target class [MarketsouhaibController] does not exist. laravel 8

The following stracktrace is shown:

```
try {
  $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
} catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
}
```

in tutorial video it work but with my laravel 8  does not work ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class does not exist. problem in laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882034/target-class-does-not-exist-problem-in-laravel-8)

Comment: Could you add your api.php/web.php files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

Answer (score 3):

From the lack of details I am guessing you are using the original controller routing syntax `Route::get('/', 'MarketsouhaibController@index')`, the syntax we all have been using for a long time, and this is a common issue. This syntax worked till Laravel 7. From 8 they changed it.

From Laravel 8, a new syntax is introduced and is the new standard. You have two options now. You either use the *String Syntax* or *PHP callable syntax* as shown below.

```
//string syntax
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\MarketsouhaibController@index')
```

```
//php callable syntax
use App\Http\Controllers\MarketsouhaibController; //must be placed at the top of routes

Route::get('/', [MarketsouhaibController::class, 'index']);
```

But if you still want to use the original auto-prefixed controller routing just follow the following steps.

1. Navigate to your `RouteServiceProvider`
2. Add `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';`

A personal suggestion, before starting please read the documentations. There are there for a reason. The solution I posted is also available in the [Documentation provided by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x) and the [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade) they posted.

Comment: This sorted my Issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can see carefully namespace in controller and route, must be same, it solve for me

Answer (score 0):

run this:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Please provide a short description how your answer solves the problem. thank you!