# Laravel package development - Target class [ControllerName] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, psr-4

I'm following a tutorial on how to create laravel packages.

I'm using Laravel v8.42.1 (PHP v7.4.3) and jetstream package.

I'm stuck on creating a controller for my package, I always get following error when trying to connect to my url via the laraval app (<base-url/playground):

```
Target class [TestVendor\TestPackage\Http\Controllers\PlaygroundController] does not exist.
```

The TestVendor\TestPackage\src\routes.php is recognized by the main application:

```
use TestVendor\TestPackage\Http\Controllers\PlaygroundController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/playground', [PlaygroundController::class, 'index']);
```

And is loaded from my ServiceProvider class:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/resources/views', 'playground');
loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes.php');
```

My namespacing is also normally correctly written in the composer.json of my package:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "TestVendor\\TestPackage\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

And I have my PlaygroundController in src/Http/Controllers/PlaygroundController.php:

```
namespace TestVendor\TestPackage\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class PlaygroundController extends Controller
{

  public function index()
  {
    return view('playground::hello');
  }

}
```

The view is also in the right package.
I'm using https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager to scaffold my packages.
Did multiple composer auto-load and composer updates.

It seems my controller is not recognized in the main application, I think somewhere my name spacing is not correct?

I already had a look at:

- [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)
  Solution did not work
- [Target class does not exist. problem in laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882034/target-class-does-not-exist-problem-in-laravel-8/63882104)
  Solution did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have namespaced your controller as:

```
namespace TestVendor\TestPackage\Http\Controllers;
```

In the line above though you say:

> And I have my PlaygroundController in src/Http/PlaygroundController.php:

Unless that is a typo, you need to add a `Controllers` directory underneath `Http` and put your `PlaygroundController` in there:

```
src/Http/Controllers/PlaygroundController.php
```

For `psr-4` autoloading, your folder structure and namespaces should mimic each other.

Comment: That was indeed a typo, if that was the solution I would be very happy. I will edit the correct path
Edit: corrected the mistake

Comment: There was indeed a mistake with the namespaces. My controller was named TEstVendor thats why it was not picked up.